# Может ли одновременно выполняться потоков больше, чем corePoolSize, пока очередь не заполнена?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Про класс ThreadPoolExecutor в документации сказано:

> When a new task is submitted in method execute(java.lang.Runnable), and fewer than corePoolSize
>   threads are running, a new thread is created to handle the request,
>   even if other worker threads are idle. If there are more than
>   corePoolSize but less than  maximumPoolSize threads running, a new
>   thread will be created only if the queue is full. By setting 
>   corePoolSize and maximumPoolSize the same, you create a fixed-size
>   thread pool. By setting  maximumPoolSize to an essentially unbounded
>   value such as Integer.MAX_VALUE, you allow the pool to accommodate an
>   arbitrary number of concurrent tasks.

Если я правильно перевожу, то это означает следующее:

Когда прибывает новая задача, и количество выполняющихся в данный момент потоков меньше, чем corePoolSize, то для обработки запроса
создаётся новый поток, даже если другие рабочие потоки простаивают. Если же работает потоков больше, чем corePoolSize, 
но меньше, чем maximumPoolSize, то новый поток будет создан, только если очередь заполнена (если же очередь не заполнена,
то задача добавляется в очередь). Устанавливая corePoolSize = maximumPoolSize, 
вы создаёте пул потоков фиксированного размера. Установив maximumPoolSize существенно большой величины, 
такой как Integer.MAX_VALUE, вы позволяете пулу вмещать произвольное число параллельных задач.

То есть, значит ли это, что, пока очередь не заполнена, в пуле потоков фиксированного размера одновременно выполняться потоков больше, чем corePoolSize, не может?

Comment: Судя по всему, может. Например, если одновременно появляется много заданий (больше `maximumPoolSize`), и они завершаются, то в течение `keepAliveTime` бежит больше чем `maximumPoolSize` потоков, хотя они все и простаивают.

Comment: Ну, то есть это может произойти только после того, как очередь хотя бы один раз будет полностью заполнена?

Comment: Да. В начале не бежит вообще ни одного, пока не придёт первое задание (если только не указано `prestartCoreThread()` и т. п.).